# VBS Delete Row from File

Tags: vbscript

I'm currently having trouble deleting the first two rows from a text file. I'm using the following code below. It work perfect on a small text file but it doesn't work on very large text files.The file I've been trying to get this to work on is over 130,000kb in size.

Im not receiving any error messages, it just delete everything in the file leaving it completely blank. Is there anyway i can get this to work?

```
Const FOR_READING = 1 
Const FOR_WRITING = 2 
strFileName = "\\File\test Scp\ZRAS.txt" 
iNumberOfLinesToDelete = 2

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING) 
strContents = objTS.ReadAll 
objTS.Close 

arrLines = Split(strContents, vbNewLine) 
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING) 

For i=0 To UBound(arrLines) 
If i > (iNumberOfLinesToDelete - 1) Then 
  objTS.WriteLine arrLines(i) 
End If 
Next 


MSGBOX "Done"
```

Comment: Your title says "VBS", which appears to refer to VBScript. Your tag says "vb.net". Your code looks like VB6. Which of the three is it? They're not the same thing.

Comment: Works OK for me as VBA. May be something isn't supported in VBS. Note that you are writing to your source file and destroying it in the process. If something goes wrong the data is gone. Better to write to a new file, then delete the old (or rename to a BAK name perhaps with a date in the filename) and rename the new file into place.

Comment: I'm using VBS i fixed the tag. I tried writing to a new file and that didn't work. It work perfect for small files but the file im working on is very large and for some reason it will not wont work on it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't waste memory and cycles on .ReadAll(), Split(), and Array looping. Just do:

```
...
Set tsIn  = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING) 
Set tsOut = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING) 

tsIn.SkipLine  ' could use a loop to skip first n lines
tsIn.SkipLine

Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   tsOut.WriteLine tsIn.ReadLine()
Loop
tsIn.Close 
tsOut.Close
```

(not tested)

Comment: I tried the code and I'm receiving an error message. It says error : Input past end of file . code: 800A003E. would you have any idea as to why i would be receiving this error?. All i did was add     Const FOR_READING = 1 
Const FOR_WRITING = 2 
strFileName = "\\File\test Scp\ZRAS.txt" before Set tsIn  = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING)

Comment: Nevermind i'm was able to fix that issue but im getting another error message..invaild procedure call or arugment  code:800A0005. Im going to post the code below

Comment: @user2974995 did you ever get the complete script working? If so could you please post?